# Flyway and JOOQ for AWS Aurora DB/embedded MySQL

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, flyway, jooq, serverless-framework

The question I'm going to ask might be a bit more of a *'proof of concept'* area, so I fully expect to find out that it's not possible to achieve what I want.

**Background:**

1. I have deployed [AWS Aurora](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/details/) database cluster using [Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com/framework/). Cluster connection details are stored as follows:

   - **Endpoint URL** - Stored as String in the [AWS Parameter Store](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/systems-manager/parameter-store/) and exists among CloudFormation outputs.
   - **Master Password** - Randomly generated during the Serverless deployment and stored as a SecureString in the AWS Parameter Store; decryptable by given lambdas only (in other words - no-one knows the password)
   - **Master Username** - hardcoded, not going to change
2. Serverless Build invokes [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) migration scripts to create the Aurora database schema. This is done using AWS lambda-backed custom resource, thus it has access to SSM (Parameter Store) to initialise DB connection.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

Maven build that invokes [JOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/) code generation using the given Aurora DB (which is based on MySQL) above.

**What I've tried and problems I've faced:**

- During the Serverless deployment create a read-only user for the Aurora DB. The login details could as well be hardcoded. However, at this stage, Maven build is unaware about the cluster endpoint URL.
- Have embedded MySQL database during Maven build. Replicate Flyway migration to this embedded database as well. However, all my attempts to integrate Flyway & JOOQ to embedded MySQL DB have failed due to connection issues. Additionally, this approach will have further complications when I integrate my build process to a CI pipeline.
- I was considering having AWS Lambda being invoked during the Maven build. It would have to return a packaged JAR that contains JOOQ generated code and would add the JAR to the sources. Haven't tried it as it seems to be too much overhead for what is required.

Another concern I have for this design - currently Aurora cluster runs on the security group that allows ingress from anywhere (for debug purposes). However, this will change to only access ingress from its own group that will restrict access to only lambdas sharing same security group.

Has anyone tried to achieve anything similar? Do you have any suggestions for my approach?

Comment: > *"However, all my attempts to integrate Flyway & JOOQ to embedded MySQL DB have failed due to connection issues"* - Could you perhaps be more specific?

Comment: Hi Lukas, thanks for your reply. I've decided to go with a re-worked first approach. Having serverless build to create read-only user, return cluster reader endpoint as a CloudFormation output and grep it for maven build (jooq generator) properties.

Comment: That's great! Would be interesting for future readers to read about your decision in a bit more detail - you can provide an answer to your own Stack Overflow question.